# How to position JButton in a JFrame window?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, layout-manager

My program is about a supermarket. I want to position the `JButton` 'b1' just below `JLabel` 'l1' and also below `JTextField` 'jt1'. I want the `JButton` 'b1' to also be in the centre but below 'l1' and 'jt1'. Below is the `delivery()` method of my program:

```
public static void delivery()
{
    final JFrame f1 = new JFrame("Name");
    f1.setVisible(true);
    f1.setSize(600,200);
    f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    f1.setLocation(700,450);

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();

    final JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Enter your name: ");

    final JTextField jt1 = new JTextField(20);

    JButton b1 = new JButton("Ok");
    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            input1 = jt1.getText();
            f1.setVisible(false);
        }
    });

    p1.add(b1);
    p1.add(l1);
    p1.add(jt1);
    f1.add(p1);


    final JFrame f2 = new JFrame("Address");
    f2.setVisible(true);
    f2.setSize(600,200);
    f2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    f2.setLocation(700,450);

    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();

    final JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Enter your address: ");

    final JTextField jt2 = new JTextField(20);

    JButton b2 = new JButton("Ok");
    b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            input2 = jt2.getText();
            f2.setVisible(false);
        }
    });

    p2.add(b2);
    p2.add(l2);
    p2.add(jt2);
    f2.add(p2);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please stop wasting __TIME__, and do as recommended in your previous posts. Read [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). The way you coding is too __BAD__, using Multiple `JFrame` for a single application, writing `JFrame.setVisible(boolean)` much before the size of the `JFrame` has been realized, using wicked hard coded location parameters (who knows, will these work on the computer next door), using excessive static blocks for no reason. Its time you __better__ stop working and start reading the basics right, before you set out on your __ENDEAVOUR__ :-)

Comment: @nIcE cOw im juz 14 and i juz learnt java for like 2 years and im not a guy who has a degree in computers or something like that. i juz know the elementary stuff. and i dont have time to read basics right now as im in Grade 10 and its a very important year for me. i need to focus in other subjects too. i dont have time to read thick, fat books right now and thats why im learning via YouTube. all i need is a little help

Comment: Are you being forced to make something you don't want to ? I hope you hadn't jumped to Grade 10, you must have taken the long road from Grade 1 onwards(and I do hope you understand why this long road). Like I said before stop __wasting time__ and focus on __other subjects__, if this is not where your interest lies. 2 years is a long time to learn something, or at least to get the basics right.

Comment: v only started learning java like when we were in grade 8. and by 'we' i mean my whole class.

Comment: `i dont have time` Then use one of the basic layout managers, and don't be so picky where the components end up.  For instance, put the label, textfield and button on the same line using a BoxLayout. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: and im interested in computers. i just dont have time to read other books for reference.

Comment: And what about hard work? You think you will learn to program by asking us to solve every problem for you?

Comment: i only need help urgently as i need to complete my project. and submission is 1 week ahead. if it was anything else i would have spent my time researching and reading books. but not this time due to limited time to complete project.

Comment: You should think about that earlier. Also, most of YT tutorials will just cause more issues.

Comment: i have 6 projects to do and this was my penultimate one. :(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a matter that is 'urgent'.  It is too localized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the GridBagLayout Class. It's for custom designing using Constraints.

Answer (score 3):

You can use multiple JPanels to get close to what you want:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MyGui {

    public static void delivery()
    {
        JFrame f1 = new JFrame("Name");
        f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        f1.setBounds(200, 100, 500, 300);
        Container cpane = f1.getContentPane();

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p1, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));  //Horizontal

        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Enter your name: ");
        JTextField jt1 = new JTextField(20);
        jt1.setMaximumSize( jt1.getPreferredSize() );

        p1.add(l1);
        p1.add(jt1);

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(); 
        p2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p2, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)); //Vertical

        p2.add(p1);

        JButton b1 = new JButton("Ok");
        p2.add(b1);
        cpane.add(p2);

        f1.setVisible(true);

    }
}



public class SwingProg {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        MyGui.delivery();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `f1.setBounds(200, 100, 500, 300);`  Better to call `f1.pack();` immediately before `f1.setVisible(true);`.  +1 in any case.  :)

Comment: Yeah, I know.  But pack() always makes the gui too small, and for messing around setBounds() works fine--that is until you call both pack() and setBounds() and then you spend the next 2 hours trying to figure out why setBounds() won't change the size of the window. :(

Comment: Try adding some layout padding and an `EmptBorder`.  That often makes a GUI feel less 'crowded'.